# Protractor browser.driver.getCurrentUrl vs browser.getCurrentUrl

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I'm running an Angular app and I'm trying to get the current URL when testing on protractor. Which one to use?

`browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()` or `browser.getCurrentUrl()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is an Angular application under test - use `browser`, otherwise - `browser.driver`.

To quote @jmr from a [relevant github issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/634):

> If you need to interact with a non-Angular page, you may access the wrapped webdriver instance directly with `browser.driver`.

---

Though, note that *both are gonna work if this is Angular application under test*. Some people even said that found `browser.driver` more reliable if it the sync time is longer than usual:

> Just to add to this - I find that browser.driver works better on AngularJS apps that take time to sync. I have tried both and for some reason browser.driver is more reliable.

Though, I've personally used `browser.getCurrentUrl()` and cannot recall any problems.