# Protractor : use browser or browser.driver methods?

Tags: node.js, protractor

When using `protractor`, the global variable `browser` appears to have all the functionality of `browser.driver`.

I am specifically asking this because I am not sure whether to use `browser.wait` or `browser.driver.wait` as they both appear to be the same method, and I also saw that a lot of the `browser.driver` methods are available in `browser` (if not all).

So what is the recommended way to call those methods `browser.method` or `browser.driver.method`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory the distinction is simple: *If this is an Angular application under test - use browser, otherwise - browser.driver.*

---

A little bit more to the story:

Protractor wraps around `WebDriverJS` - javascript selenium bindings - as a part of that it wraps the selenium driver object itself leaving you the access to the pure WebDriverJS driver via `browser.driver`.

---

There are though other takeaways, please take a look at this related threads:

- [Protractor browser.driver.getCurrentUrl vs browser.getCurrentUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439399/protractor-browser-driver-getcurrenturl-vs-browser-getcurrenturl)
- [browser.driver vs browser. Which one to use?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/634)

Answer (score 5):

**Some browser methods are the same...**

The browser object is made up by composition of WebDriver methods and Protractor specific methods. So methods like `sleep`, `wait`, and `getCurrentUrl` are copied over from WebDriver (see the [browser.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L37)). So should you use `browser` or `browser.driver`? Well, if it is listed in the link above, they are the exact same thing.

**Some browser methods are not...**

However, not every method is just copied over. For methods like `get`, the browser is implemented differently in [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L648) vs [selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L995). For Angular pages, you should use `browser.get`. This will wait for Angular to be stable before moving on to other commands before moving onto other commands.

**When in doubt, check out the documentation**

So when you navigate to [protractortest.org/#/api](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api), you will see a list of `browser` methods that are Protractor specific and "inherited from webdriver.WebDriver". The methods that follow "inherited from webdriver.WebDriver" are the same method if you decide to use `browser` or `browser.driver`.