# browser.driver.wait vs browser.wait

Tags: angular, protractor

I have started writing test cases for protractor and I found `browser.wait` method which allows to wait until some condition is fulfilled. Sometimes I can see in code snippets `browser.driver.wait` instead of `browser.wait`.

What is the difference?

I have been searching for the answer but I only found difference between `sleep` and `wait` in protractor.

Here my configuration (I use cucumber framework):

```
        "protractor": "5.4.1",
        "protractor-cucumber-framework": "6.1.1",
        "cucumber":"5.0.2"
```

Comment: The answer will depend on the your protractor version. When I wrote test cases, Protractor inherently implemented a queue to hold async tasks. But this queue only held async tasks from the protractor and each task ran one after the other. When you write `browser.wait()` you are probably adding the wait in the queue, but through `browser.driver.wait()` you are directly accessing the selenium driver and the task doesn't go in the queue. This means the `driver.wait()` will not wait for previous tasks in the queue to execute before executing itself.

Comment: I have added the configuration. It seems like the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @xyz , would you like to add your comment as the answer for the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor : use browser or browser.driver methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255660/protractor-use-browser-or-browser-driver-methods)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer will depend on your protractor version.

When I wrote test cases, Protractor inherently implemented a queue to hold async tasks. But this queue only held async tasks from Protractor (like: `element(by.partialLinkText('Doge')).click(), etc`) and each task ran one after the other. When you write `browser.wait()` you are probably adding the wait in the Protractor queue but through `browser.driver.wait()` you are directly accessing the selenium driver and the task doesn't go in the queue. This means the `driver.wait()` will not wait for previous tasks in the queue to execute before executing itself.

I don't believe that the current version of Protractor still have the queue and it promotes use of `async/await` and if there is no queue what will be the benefit of one over the other but nevertheless, when we use anything related to `driver` it means we are accessing selenium driver API directly.